# Delphi - Executável com comportamento diferente em máquinas diferentes

Tags: delphi

Eu quis criar um efeito de transição para um form, então, no evento `OnShow`, setei a propriedade `AlphaBlend := 0` e, no `OnActivate:`

```
  for i := 55 to 255 do
  begin
    AlphaBlendValue := i;
    Update;
    sleep(1);
  end;
```

Funciona perfeitamente em meu equipamento, fazendo com que o form fique visível gradualmente, em torno de dois décimos de segundo, o que dá um efeito mais agradável. No entanto, ao copiar o executável para outros dois equipamentos (por sinal, idênticos ao meu - mesma marca e modelo), o efeito demora cerca de dois segundos (!), dando uma impressão péssima!

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que poderia estar acontecendo?

Comment: Pode ser uma demora no processamento do comando Update. Troca ele por Application.ProcessMessages e vê se produz algum resultado.

Comment: Originalmente o comando era Application.ProcessMessages. Eu troquei para Update justamente imaginando que poderia haver uma fila de mensagens causando lentidão. Mas o efeito é o mesmo.

Comment: Tirando o hardware, os softwares nas máquinas são os mesmos (ou parecidos)? Windows? Antivírus? No gerenciador de tarefas, o processamento está parecido?

Comment: Só uma pergunta, estamos falando de VCL ou Firemonkey?

Comment: São máquinas com softwares parecidos, mesmo Windows, mesmo antivirus. Vou olhar o gerenciador de tarefas. A bliblioteca utilizada é a VCL.

Comment: Examinei o gerenciador de tarefas e o processamento desse código não parece estar pesando em nada. CPU passou de 0 para 1 durante um piscar de olhos e a memória aumenta 200k enquanto o form permanece aberto (sendo que o programa consome pouco mais de 6Mb).

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente nesses casos existe algum **processo** sendo executado na **Thread Principal**, e atrasando a execução do seu Looping For. Uma possível solução seria executar o Looping em uma **Thread Secundária**. Ficaria assim:

Evento `OnShow`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    AlphaBlend := true;
    AlphaBlendValue := 0;
end;
```

Evento `OnActivate`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
    MyThread: TThread;
begin
    MyThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var i: Integer;
    begin
        for i := 55 to 255 do
        begin
            TThread.Synchronize(MyThread, procedure begin
                AlphaBlendValue := i;
                Update;
                sleep(1);
            end);
        end;
    end);
    MyThread.Start;
end;
```

No evento `OnActivate` criamos uma **Thread Anônima**, que automaticamente será finalizada após sua execução. Seu processamento ocorre em background, até que seja chamado o comando **Synchronize**, e somente aquele processamento ocorre na Thread Principal.

Comment: Utilizei a thread mas o efeito foi o mesmo. Somente em um computador; no meu funciona perfeitamente. Fiz, ainda, outra experiência: comentei o comando sleep(1). Nesse caso, lógico, o efeito de transição se perde, mas o objetivo era testar se o problema estaria nesse comando. O resultado foi que o form ficou visível imediatamente, mesmo no computador problemático. Fica claro que há algum problema no sleep.

Comment: Outro teste, substituindo o sleep(1) por: <code>for k := 0 to 500000 do ;</code>, o efeito funciona em todos os computadores. O problema é que, neste caso, iria variar conforme a velocidade do processador.